# Hi, I am currently upgrading wicket application from 1.5.3 to 6.30.0 but i am getting error and login page is not getting instantiated

Tags: wicket, wicket-6

org.apache.wicket.WicketRuntimeException: Can't instantiate page using constructor 'public com.ecs.test.web.page.Login()'. An exception has been thrown during construction!
    at org.apache.wicket.session.DefaultPageFactory.newPage(DefaultPageFactory.java:194)

Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/inject/Inject
    at org.apache.wicket.spring.injection.annot.AnnotProxyFieldValueFactory.supportsField(AnnotProxyFieldValueFactory.java:324)
    at org.apache.wicket.injection.Injector.findFields(Injector.java:148)

Answer (score 0):

it might help tring to add Objenesis lib to your project dependencies. Wicket CI checks if this lib is available and if so, it's used to build proxy objects even if they don't provide a no args (i.e. Default) constructor.

Comment: at org.apache.wicket.Page.<init>(Page.java:132)
 at org.apache.wicket.markup.html.WebPage.<init>(WebPage.java:75)
 at wicket.page.InvalidAccessPage.<init>(InvalidAccessPage.java:11)
 at .InternalErrorPage.<init>(InternalErrorPage.java:19)
 ... 51 more